# Need jQuery code to find div containing an ul with more than 3 elements

Tags: jquery, html

I need jQuery code which I can use to find divs which are the direct parent of at least one `ul`, which in turn has more than 3 elements. When such a `div` is found, It should add the class name `target` to it.

For example, if I have the following HTML code:

**JSFiddle Here:** http://jsfiddle.net/AvkY5/

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="main_child_1">
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main_child_2">
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main_child_3">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="main_child_4">
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="main_child_4_child_1">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="main_child_4_child_2">
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main_child_5">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <div class="main_child_5_child_1">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="main_child_5_child_2">
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main_child_6">
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="main_child_6_child_1">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="main_child_6_child_2">
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main_child_6_child_3">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then in this code, the following divs should get `target` added to their class name:

- main_child_2
- main_child_4
- main_child_5_child_2
- main_child_6_child_2

What jQuery code can achieve this ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I virtually have no experience on jQuery, so I didn't want to waste time on that, and instead choose the polish the question's example in that much time.

Comment: you must assign a class to divs same name all of them. and make a nasted-loop for them. and check it what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will find all divs with a ul child, with more than 3 child elements, and add the class `target` to the div, not the ul element...

```
$(".main div > ul").filter(function() {
    return $(this).children().length > 3;
}).parent().addClass("target");
```

**Edit:** Added `.main` class, as requested.

Comment: Although this code works, can you change the `div > ul` part somehow, so that it ONLY looks for such divs inside the `main` class ? This is because this question relates to my website, and I only want this searching to happen within a specific location.

Comment: Just for information,you can also check the comparaison of filter vs nth-child to choose your solution : http://jsperf.com/filter-vs-nth-child

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
$("div").filter(function() {
    return $(this).children("ul li").length > 3;
}).addClass("target");
```

Comment: @JasonP -- True, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the best way is to use pure css "nth-child property".

Fast & Elegant

One line :

```
//(n+3) : 3 or more li
// (4) : more than 3
$( "ul li:nth-child(n+3)" ).closest("div").addClass( "target");
```

Here the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AvkY5/5/)

Comment: Result is not correct. Selects some classes that it shouldn't.

Comment: if you use (n+3), it select 3 or more li child, if you use (4), it select the right div for your use, like said in //comments

Answer (score 1):

You can use the nth-child to do this:

```
    # There is probably a more elegant way to get to the div parent, 
    #but this should get you headed in the right direction
    $("div ul li:nth-child(4)").parent().parent().addClass("target")
```